# Finding index of $p_{k}$ element in the original sorted array if elements were to be removed using a specific condition

Tags: algorithms, number-theory, permutations, enumeration

Consider a sorted list of numbers $C_{0}=\{0,1,2,3,...,n-1\}$ from where one element will be eliminated at each step. We are also given a value $L$ in $[0, 1)$ and let the indexing start from $0$.

Given a value $L_{0} = L$ in $[0, 1)$, we find $a_{0} = ⌊L_{0}⋅n⌋$ and remove the $a_{0}^{th}$ element $p_{0}$ from $C_{0}$ to get $C_{1} = C_{0} / \{p_{0}\}$, i.e. $C_{1}$ is $C_{0}$ without element $p_{0}$. Next we find $L_{1} = (L_{0}⋅n) − a_0$ to remove $a_{1}^{th}$ element $p_{1}$ from $C_{1}$ to get $C_{2} = C_{1} / \{p_{1}\}$ and so on.

Continue in this way, in the $k^{th}$ step, for $k = 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n-1$, we get $a_{k} = ⌊L_{k}⋅(n−k)⌋$, take $p_{k}$ to be the $a_{k}^{th}$ element of $C_{k}$ and define $C_{k+1}=C_{k}/\{p_{k}\}$ and $L_{k+1} = L_{k}⋅(n−k)−a_{k}$.

Is it possible to figure out the index of element $p_{k}$ in $C_{0}$ in the $k^{th}$ step without removing $p_1, p_2, ..., p_{k−1}$ elements from $C_{0}$ in the previous steps? This problem seems to be based on the [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system).

Cross-post from Math Stack Exchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3757056/finding-index-of-p-k-element-in-the-original-sorted-set-of-numbers-if-elemen).

Comment: In the computation you have the index and require the element. In the title you seem to be asking the inverse. Either way, at each step, the information required to answer either one of those questions is equivalent to knowing the collection of all elements that have been removed (or that remain).

Comment: I am just trying to avoid actually removing elements from $C_{0}$ and get the index of element $p_{k}$ in $C_{0}$ for the $k^{th}$ step had we actually gone about removing elements from $C_{0}$.

Comment: Also it is important to note that the index that I get at every $k^{th}$ step only helps me get $p_{k}$ from the specific $C_{k}$ list of numbers and not from $C_{0}$ (except for k = 0, obviously).

Comment: Can we assume that $L$ is rational?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3757056/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/128352/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @orlp, yeah we can assume that $L$ is rational if it makes it easier to solve the problem.

Comment: @D.W., I'll not cross post questions on multiple stack exchange sites going forward. Sorry for the trouble.